# Java Array help Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

Beginner here and I need help with this Exception out of bounds error. I am really Stuck !
Trying to multiply matrices. Please help

```
package arrayPractice1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type how much rows will matrix A have");
        int rowA = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type how much columns will matrix A have");
        int colA = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type how much rows will matrix B have");
        int rowB = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type how much columns will matrix B have");
        int colB = in.nextInt();

        int[][] matrixA = new int[rowA][colA];
        int[][] matrixB = new int[rowB][colB];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter value for row " + i + " and column " + j);
                matrixA[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixB.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixB[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter value for row " + i + " and column " + j);
                matrixB[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        in.close();

        int[][] multiply = new int[colA][rowB];
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Mult. of matrixA and matrixB");

        for (int i = 0; i < rowA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < colB; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < rowA; k++) {
                    sum = sum + matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
                }
                multiply[i][j] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(multiply));

    }

}
```

Comment: What line? And what have you done to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < collB; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < rowA; k++) {
                sum = sum + matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
            multiply[i][j] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
```

here you are checking if i is less than collB and while this is true you are making j larger than the matrix[k][j] allows causing the index out of bounds error.